# Sending users to different sections of survey

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

So I just created a google forms survey and wondered if its possible to send the users to different sections.

I am looking for at way to direct half of the users directly to section 2 and have the other half only see section 1.

User 1: Sees only section 1

User 2: Sees only section 2

User 3: Sees only section 1

and so on

Is there a way to keep a counter in google scripts that that sends the users directly to a section depending on whenever its odd or even without having them answer any questions first?

Answer (score 1):

On the form you can specify that after each of those sections, the form should be submitted instead of continuing on to the next section.

Then, you can get a pre-filled URL for each of the different users by:

1. Go to the form editor, and on the first page of the form, add a multiple choice question that has each different user as the options.
2. Then, check the box that says *Go to page based on answer*.

   - Next to the multiple choice options for each user, choose *Go to page X*, depending on which users should go to which sections.
3. In the menu, go to `Responses > Get pre-filled URL`.
4. For each user, select that user from the first multiple choice question and then click `Submit`.

   - In the new URL to share the pre-filled form, change **`viewform?`** to **`formResponse?`** and add **`&continue=continue`** to the end of the URL.

Repeat this for each of the different users and then give the users these new URLs for them to fill out the form.